# "Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded" Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I recently installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and I am having trouble making changes to a Controller that I just added.

I keep getting this error message:

> "Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded."

Here are the steps I performed leading up to that:

1. Clicked on New Project
2. Went to Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web > Visual Studio 2012
3. Clicked on ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application and clicked OK.
4. Selected Internet Application and clicked on OK.
5. Clicked on Debug > Start Debugging.
6. Added a new controller by right-clicking on the Controllers folder and then clicking on Add Controller.
7. Named my Controller and clicked on Add.
8. Tried to delete the contents, but got the error message, "Changes are not allowed if the assembly has not been loaded."

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I figured out the answer.  I was in debug mode and all I had to do was stop debugging and it worked.